# Summer 16 Release Exam

Tags: certification, summer-16

I recently got certified in Salesforce 201 last month. I received an email last week stating that i have to write the summer 16 exam before March 3rd 2017. It said i have to get 83% in the exam and i will be given three tries to take the exam. It also had a link for Summer 16 release materials. But when i click on the link i could not find anything. I am wondering what material should i exactly be studying up for my release exam. If someone could point me in the right direction, i would be mighty helpful. Since this is my first time facing a release exam, pointers will help.

Comment: You need to study release notes of summer 16. It's non proctored and easy test. Best luck.

Comment: HI Kiran, just to confirm Is it the 420 pages of pdf available in the documentation?

Comment: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/salesforce_release_notes.htm

Comment: pdf version is : https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer16_release_notes.pdf

Comment: Yes that is correct...if you just go through in high level you would be able to clear test.

Comment: Actually, this test has nothing to do with the Summer '16 release this time.  It's all historical knowledge, but a lot of the questions are for edge capabilities.  For example, there is a question of:
Sales representatives at Universal Containers require approval for large discounts on opportunities and Sales management to automate the submission once the opportunity reaches the stage. What two features can an administrator use to meet this requirement?  Should be Approvals and Process Builder, but Visual Flow could too.  Also, the question on Chatter Questions; all answers could be accurate.

Answer (score 5):

First of all there is no certification named 201 . The certification name is "Salesforce Certified Administrator"

I checked that the release readiness video is not yet released and expect to come in coming weeks (SAFE HARBOUR)

You can check [here](http://www.salesforce.com/customer-resources/releases/summer16/training-coming-summer16.jsp) for release specific training's once it is live .

Having said that there are multiple resources for you to still help and pass the exam

**1.Release Notes**

You can go through them in form of [pdf](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer16_release_notes.pdf) or [HTML](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/salesforce_release_notes.htm) .

**2.There is Trailhead Module for [Summer 16](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/summer_16)**

**3.Release Overview Deck**

This will need your SFDC credentials and log into success.salesforce.com to access and download the deck from [here](https://success.salesforce.com/0693A000005tlfe)

**4.Release readiness video.**

Please check these [links](https://www.salesforce.com/video/release-readiness-summer-2016) for detailed video from product team at salesforce.